# React native debugger Installation on Mac m1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, electron, apple-m1, react-native-debugger

- I have installed the react native debugger on mac-book pro m1 to debug react native applications.
- While debugging it shows you are using react-devtools 4.13 and please downgrade to <4.11. While trying to install react-devtools 4.11 using `npm install --save react-devtools@4.11` it showed electron error i.e.

**HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.4/electron-v9.4.4-darwin-arm64.zip**

- On googling I found some forums regarding this on github
  [1]: https://github.com/mglukhovsky/react-devtools-components-blank
  It says to use resolution for electron package i.e.

"resolutions": {
"electron": "^11.0.1"
}

Can someone please tell me how to use this resolution thing to install react-?devtools < 4.11 ?

I googled a lot but did not get steps to install react devtools < 4.11 in order to make react native debugger work.

I also tried downloading react-devtools 4.10 locally and changed electron package version to 11.0 to support m1 chip on mac. After that too react-native-debugger showed the same issue.

**

```
Unsupported DevTools backend version
You are running react-devtools version 4.13.4-51ebccc374.
This requires bridge protocol version 1. However the current backend version uses bridge protocol version 0.
To fix this, downgrade the DevTools NPM package:
npm i -g react-devtools@"<4.11.0"
```

**

All I want to know step by step how to make react-native-debugger run on macbook m1 chip without that error/warning ?

How to use resolutions to resolve the electron version error while installing react-devtools for macbook m1 ?

Comment: I am not able to get how to use resolution mentioned in this post
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20454
React DevTools should bump the Electron version to 11.0.1 for darwin-arm64 builds

Comment: share your eid please......will check it

Comment: I answered the same. Checkout this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71262895/2602054

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error while installing `react-devtools@3.6.3` for React Native  `0.60`.

I ran following command to install the devtools:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 npm install -g react-devtools@3.6.3
```

If you want install other versions on M1 Mac then change it in the above command.